# What's the meaning of "artistic integrity"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I admire her **artistic integrity.**

I think artistic means-relating to art, but what's will be the actual interpretation of the sentence?

Comment: Please explain your downvote so that the question may be improved (or closed if invalid).

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hard to define 'artistic integrity' exactly, and artists write essays on this subject!

But, roughly, it means:

**Prioritizing one's art itself and the realization of one's artistic vision over other aspects of working as an artist.**

In other words, an artist with *artistic integrity* cares less about fame, money, having an easy career, and other things that people might try and acquire, and more about *making their at* at any cost, and *truly using their individual artistic voice*.

The speaker is expressing that the artist she is talking about has "artistic integrity" and that she respects the artist for that.

Comment: Is the phrase implies figurative meaning?

Comment: Please explain your downvote so that the answer may be improved.

Answer (score 0):

It means she values the artistic purity of her creations.

In practice, it means artists will not take commissions (paid work) they disagree with or in formats they do not work with.  A sculptor would probably make a lousy painter.

It also means she likely does not follow 'trends' or 'fads' in art.

It can also mean she has high reserve prices at the gallery. :)

Comment: Having "artistic integrity" does not say anything about the prices or values of the artist's work, nor does it mean anything about the likelihood of their taking commissions in any set of circumstances.   This is completely inaccurate.

Comment: Please remain *topical and kind*, in accordance with this site's code of conduct. I would refer you to the discussion of the concept of artistic integrity at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_integrity - notice that nothing connecting "integrity" and "price", or availability of commissions, is discussed. Also notice that "artistic integrity" is also used for artists such as authors, who do not show their works in a gallery at all. I invite you to justify your claims in a civil and empirical way by citing some published usage or commentary

Comment: @BadZen No, I actually live in the real world which is why I say 'in practice' to distinguish from some theoretical definition.  "I'm not selling that work for less than $10,000.  I have integrity!"  Yes, they think that way.  OP could just read the dictionary, they come here lean how the language is actually used to communicate.

Comment: And yet the discussion I just pointed you do, with citation to supporting sociological evidence, speaks of "the widespread idea that artists can have integrity if they do not commercialize their art or are financially successful".    This seems to completely contradict your "in my world" hip-shot here, so I still think you need to at least justify your "real world" definition somehow.  Remember this question is about *use and meaning of a phrase in the English language*, and not your opinion on what artists are like or how they should or should not be.

Comment: @BadZen Nope.  My Answer is fine.  I provide a definition of 'artistic integrity' then provide examples of colloquial usage.  There's no point in citing an air quality study during a forest fire.  Don't reduce this forum to "Check the OED."